# If doesn't work at bash script

Tags: bash

This is not the complete code, 2 first lines are only for "debug" purpose, I'm new on bash scripting and I don't know why if `ls $ACTUAL/${BACKUP_DIR}/${NOMBRE}_*.tgz | wc -l` returns 2 ,the script execute the then clause...

```
COPIAS=$(ls $ACTUAL/${BACKUP_DIR}/${NOMBRE}_*.tgz | wc -l)
echo ${COPIAS}
if [ $(ls $ACTUAL/${BACKUP_DIR}/${NOMBRE}_*.tgz | wc -l)>5 ]
    then
        echo "more than 5"
    else
        echo "5 or less"
fi
```

Comment: Dont parse the output from ls.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: related http://serverfault.com/questions/477503/check-if-array-is-empty-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` is a normal command, so `>` is treated as a redirection. You can use `[[` (which is a keyword) instead. Alternatively, you can escape `>` to `\>` so it isn't treated as a redirection.

Beware that `>` is for string comparison. To compare two numbers you would use `-gt`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 array=("$ACTUAL/${BACKUP_DIR}/${NOMBRE}_"*.tgz)

 if [[ ${#array[@]} -gt 5 ]]  # -gt: arithmetic operator greater-than
 then
   echo "more than 5"
 else
   echo "5 or less"
 fi
```